# Exporting an Excel in Python/PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a pandas dataframe that I would like to export to excel and when I run the following code;

```
AmortizingFloatingCashflows = pd.DataFrame(AmortizingFloatingCashflows)
AmortizingFloatingCashflows.to_excel('AmortizingFloatingCashflows.xlsx')
```

I am getting the following error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/../Amortizing Swap/Amortizing swap.py", line 116, in <module>
    AmortizingFloatingCashflows.to_excel('AmortizingFloatingCashflows.xlsx')
  File "/Users/../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 2252, in to_excel
    formatter.write(
  File "/Users/../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/formats/excel.py", line 934, in write
    writer = ExcelWriter(  # type: ignore[abstract]
  File "/Users/../venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_openpyxl.py", line 56, in __init__
    from openpyxl.workbook import Workbook
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'openpyxl'
```

I have installed openpyxl but I am still not getting it right. How best can I export the pandas dataframe into excel?

Comment: Can you run the line `import openpyxl` in you code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates that the `openpyxl` module is not installed in your Python environment. `openpyxl` is a third-party library that is required for Pandas to manipulate Excel files.

You can install 'openpyxl' by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt:

```bash
pip install openpyxl
```

Once you have installed `openpyxl`, you should be able to run the code without any errors.

Comment: I have installed it as shown below and but I still get the same error; 
Requirement already satisfied: openpyxl in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (3.2.0b1)
Requirement already satisfied: et-xmlfile in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from openpyxl) (1.1.0)

Comment: You need to install the package in the virtual environment you're using to run the code.   By default venvs are isolated from system packages